# Traduction de l'anglais « man's man »

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

**I**

On trouve une définition de « *man's man* » dans le dictionnaire anglais-français « Harrap's »; c'est « *un vrai homme, un homme que les autres hommes admirent* ». Cependant, dans cette source, [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Man%27s%20Man), on trouve une définition précise et dans cette définition le fait que un « man's man » est admiré des autres hommes, *et des femmes*, n'est qu'une conséquence de ce qui est le corps de la définition (« For these reasons, women want him and men want to be him. »).

Ne pas confondre avec « *man of men* » qui signifierait selon moi « homme avec des qualités exceptionnelles » (« man of supreme excellence » pour citer un dictionnaire d'Oxford).

On a tendance à penser que « vrai homme » réfère aux meilleures qualités de virilité et de bravoure de l'être masculin alors que « homme que les autres hommes admirent » reste très général ; ces traductions ne sont apparemment pas très justes.

Existe-t-il en français, donc, un terme plus proche de cette définition anglaise, un terme comme peut-être « homme complet » (qui ne semble pas satisfaisant non plus) ou mieux, « homme idéal » (qui semble préférable mais n'est pas tout à fait un syntagme défini) ? À la rigueur est-ce que « homme idéal » serait une bonne traduction ?

**II**

Cependant, dans le [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-man-s-man) on touve une toute autre définition.

> a man who enjoys men's activities and being with other men:
>
> •Terry's what you'd call a man's man - you wouldn't find him at the ballet too many nights a week.

Une définition similaire dans un « Oxford English dictionary », l'[OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/man_1#man_idmg_14), tend à confirmer cela, bien qu'une divergence certaine existe.

> A man who is more popular with men than with women.

Existe-t-il des termes idiomatiques pour ces sens-ci de « man's man » ? Si oui, quel sont-ils ?

Comment: For (I), there will surely be an equivalent of the phrase in a translation of Radclyffe Hall’s _The Unlit Lamp_ (La flamme vaincue), but it’s a relatively obscure text and I have trouble finding it, alas. There are probably some other examples, but I can’t remember them with as much confidence.

Comment: "*homme idéal*" C'est gentil de parler de moi en ces termes. Alors... comme je me suis reconnu... Bon! mais vous savez bien : *honnête-homme* m'aurait suffit.

Comment: @aCOSwt Ah oui…aCOSwt…toujours le mot pour rire !

Comment: Ha! C'était pas vraiment pour rire... c'était plus une suggestion sérieuse en rapport avec un authentique idéal. J'aurais bien suggéré aussi l'*Übermensch* mais je m'étais dit qu'on le prendrait trop à la rigolade... Et pourtant!

Comment: @aCOSwt « Übermensch  », soit, pour « man of men », c'est certainement dans une bonne proximité. « Superman » est aussi un candidat pour celui-là.

Comment: C'est bien du OALD qu'il s'agit, la version papier, et je n'aurais jamais cru qu'il soit disponible en ligne. Mille mercis pour avoir déniché ce lien et m'en avoir fait part.

Answer (score 7):

*Homme idéal* est trop abstrait, l'homme idéal, ça n'existe pas. Avec *idéal*, on pourrait éventuellement suggérer *gendre idéal* mais l'expression est restrictive.

En partant de la définition de l'Urban Dictionary, en particulier *Most importantly, he will admit his faults and errors, because that is what real men do. He don't have to be gay or straight, black or white, Republic or Democrat, Atheist or Evangelical; he just does what ever he thinks makes himself a good person that he can be proud of.* je dirais simplement « ***un mec bien*** ». L'expression est courante et bien comprise et des mecs bien comme des *man's men*, il y en a.

Si on n'aime pas dire *mec*, on peut choisir *type* ou *gars* ou même :

> C'est **quelqu'un de bien**.

Sinon, les définitions du Cambridge Dictionary et de l'Oxford Dictionary évoquent un peu le « *[**beauf**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beauf)* » mais ça ajoute une composante péjorative.

Comment: +1! Tout pareil! Avec peut-être aussi pour 2/ le *kéké* et ses variantes orthographiques régionales. Je me souviens que dans la région que tu avais trouvée on distinguait le *gonzier* (plus proche du sens 1) du *gonze* (plus proche du sens 2) mais je n'ai pas retrouvé d'attestation.

Comment: 1/ Pourquoi passer tout de suite au populaire ou à l'argot ? Il n'est pasnécessaire de dénigrer le pur et simple « homme bien », ou alors cet « homme bien », ce serait quelque chose d'autre, ou faut-il oublier l'homme bien ? 2/ Ce « beauf » est loin de conférer des idées positives, c'est un mot péjoratif et en plus argotique, alors que « man's man » reste un terme laudatif *et* de la langue courante en anglais.

Comment: 1. *Mec (bien)* n'est plus de l'argot depuis longtemps, c'est un mot familier très courant. Je ne dénigre pas *homme bien* mais *mec bien* sous entend beaucoup plus de qualités. C'est une expression courante et bien établie que tout le monde emploie en France et qui correspond à la définition de l'Urban Dictionary.

Comment: 2. J'ai bien signalé que *beauf* était plus péjoratif que la définition du Cambridge Dictionary et que le sens n'était pas exactement le même. Il n'empêche que que les hommes qui n'ont d'intérêt que pour les activités traditionnellement associées aux hommes ("les vrais, les tatoués") peuvent être considérés comme des *beaufs* par ceux qui ont un esprit plus ouvert.

Comment: Quand je regarde les définitions données dans la question, il semble que l'accent soit quand-même mis sur un sorte d'admiration par d'autres hommes, sur les les activités "viriles", excluant un peu les femmes, là où un "mec bien" est plus généralement une bonne personne de sexe masculin, comme pourraît l'être une femme bien.

Comment: Mi-bon gars, mi-_sex symbol_ peut-être ?

Comment: Le mieux étant l’ennemi du bien, à en croire certains, peut-être un *type bien* serait plus consensuel.

Comment: @Personne Reçu. J'ai ajouté des propositions consensuelles :-)

Answer (score 3):

Apparemment, une traduction courante est *un vrai homme* (ou *un homme, un vrai*), à rapprocher du *un vrai, un tatoué* cité par @jiliagre en commentaire de sa réponse.

Selon moi, ce terme *un vrai homme* était autrefois utilisé presque uniquement dans un sens laudatif. De nos jours, ça peut être encore le cas, mais il est aussi utilisé dans un sens ironique, ce qui le rapproche du *beauf* également cité par @jiliagre, dans sa réponse cette fois-ci.

Je ne maitrise pas assez l'anglais pour savoir si cette ambiguïté de sens de *un vrai homme* correspond à celle de *man's man*.

Comment: Pour le premier sens (urban dictionary) j'aurais pensé à une caractérisation telle que confère le terme « BCBG », mais il manque une expression ;  ce terme n'est pas nécessairement le plus neutre ou le plus souhaitable mais il contient l'idée; je ne crois pas que l'on puisse dire « il est  BCBG » ou « c'est un homme BCBG ».  (1/2)

Comment: On rapproche ce sens d'une définition chrétienne de « vrai homme » (Un vrai homme s’efforce d’être...
•respectueux (Romains 12:10),
•serviable (1 Corinthiens 10:24),
•responsable (Galates 6:5),
•maître de ses émotions (Proverbes 16:32).
https://www.jw.org/fr/biblioth%C3%A8que/revues/g201212/qu-est-ce-qu-un-vrai-homme/) et celle-ci n'a rien à voir avec le beauf ; « man's man » non plus n'a rien à voir avec «beauf ». Donc, votre compréhension de « vrai homme » en tant que terme laudatif utilisé autrefois conviendrait si prise dans ce sens. (2/2)

Comment: De nos jours, l'expression *un vrai homme* s'éloigne beaucoup de la définition chrétienne, et est à prendre dans un sens beaucoup plus viril. Le vrai homme chrétien peut être une femme ! Le mot *homme* a malheureusement deux sens très différents en français

Comment: +1  Pour *un homme, un vrai* ... je viens justement de retrouver l'expression dans un magazine avec exactement ce sens-là. Je me demande si l'expression ne s'est pas répandue depuis le film du même nom.

Answer (score 1):

En premier lieu ailleurs on a parlé du « [mec bien](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40261) », du « bon gars » finalement (il me semble qu'on puisse aussi l'employer péjorativement ou par ironie) ; c'est probablement un « [modèle](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mod%C3%A8le/51916?q=mod%C3%A8le#51793) », un homme « à la [hauteur](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hauteur) », c'est-à-dire « capable, compétent, digne » (TLFi). Si c'était surtout un reflet de la sensualité ce serait un peu comme un [*sex-symbol*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sex_symbol) à certains égards ; un mot comme [*étalon*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9talon), l'« homme ardent aux plaisirs de l'amour » (Littré au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9talon)) ce [mâle reproducteur](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9talon/31275?q=%C3%A9talon#31207), et la notion de prototype, pourrait être utile dans ce cas-là.

En deuxième lieu, sans référence à la popularité, [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/man/593826) donne directement « il aime bien être avec ses copains ». On peut dire d'une personne que c'est *quelqu'un qui aime être avec ses copains* ; il s'agit cependant d'une phrase/locution.

Par ailleurs à mon avis Cambridge fait dans le stéréotype avec l'idée de « men's activities » alors que chez [Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man%27s%20man) on dispose intelligemment de la nuance « a man noted or admired for traditionally masculine interests and activities »  : l'homme qui excelle dans les activités traditionnellement associées aux hommes et dont on a remarqué les exploits. D'autres termes utiles selon la nuance recherchée seraient probablement l'homme « [conventionnel](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conventionnel) », « (être) vieux-[jeu](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jeu) » (« Avoir des habitudes de vie ou de pensée surannées » (TLFi) ; aux idées [arriéré](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/arri%C3%A9r%C3%A9)es... *arriéré*), « [hétéronormé](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%A9t%C3%A9ronorm%C3%A9), hétérosexiste », ou simplement dont les goûts n'incluent pas, qui est peu « stimulé » par, voire « peu éveillé » aux arts de la scène par exemple, comme notre ami Terry. Selon le contexte on pourra aussi trouver l'[*ignare*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ignare) ou le [*sectaire*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/bigot/565594) etc.

Comment: Je ne partage pas exactement votre jugement en ce qui concerne Merriam et Cambridge et je crois qu'il s'agit plutôt d'une approche linguistique un peu différente et d'une carence dans les deux définitions, cela étant dû au peu d'espace auquel s'astreignent les lexicographes, la définition du premier insinuant l'arrière plan d'une culture ancestrale alors que celle du second est plus générale. Cela mis à part, il semble que votre aperçu apporte la conclusion qu'il n'y a aucune définition fiable et qu'en vérité toutes sont applicables  pourvu qu'elles correspondent bien au contexte.

Comment: @LPH C'est aussi une question de perception. Il y a polysémie et peut-être que certains sens sont mieux ancrés que d'autres dans l'usage etc.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

> un homme au sommet de sa masculinité

> un macho

But I guess that the latter has mostly negative connotation. Nevertheless, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machismo#Positive_implications